# Do the F-16's leading edge flaps lock up at +2° when the aircraft as a whole is supersonic, or when the airflow over its wings is supersonic?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, aircraft-performance, f-16, high-lift-device

My question is: do the leading edge flaps lock upright when the aircraft *as a whole* is supersonic, or when airflow over  wings of the aircraft is supersonic?

Comment: Are you referring to slats or flaps on the leading edge?

Comment: The F16 has  only LEF's (Leading Egde Flaps),for maneuvering .For  landing use the  flaperon s -TEF (trailing edge flaps)

Comment: To those who voted to close, what is unclear about the question?

Comment: @GeorgeGeo F-16 LEF's are lowered for landing too (high alpha). Check out any picture of an F-16 landing for a reference.

Comment: Trust me I know that ,but the question is about the upward trend of the LEF's

Answer (score 0):

There will still be airflow over both the body and the wings of the F-16 or any other aircraft when it flies supersonic.

Moreover, the F-16 features a blended wing-body which makes it hard to strictly separate the two. The body of the aircraft produces some amount of lift. Your question seems to ask if this lift is required, at supersonic speeds in particular.

I believe the F-16 could still fly if one was made without having any lift produced by the body itself and probably fly at supersonic speed, but this is sheer conjecture.

Perhaps you will get a more satisfying answer if you clarify the question a bit?

Comment: AlphaCentauri Not talk about the lifting forces here just control laws which programming the leading edges movement